# where convert(varchar(10) for date between not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use the BETWEEN for dates but it keeps failing in that it just returns all results if I do = or in it works fine but between doesn't can anyone help, thanks

```
WHERE CASE 
    WHEN [BVContact] IS NOT NULL
        THEN convert(VARCHAR(10), [ContactStarted], 103)
    WHEN [TelephoneConsultationStartedBy] IS NOT NULL
        THEN convert(VARCHAR(10), [TelephoneConsultationStarted], 103)
    WHEN [HomeVisitContactBy] IS NOT NULL
        THEN convert(VARCHAR(10), [HomeVisitContactStarted], 103)
    ELSE ''
    END between '01/10/2016'
    AND '02/10/2016'
```

Comment: What dialect of SQL is this please? What kind of data are you working with?

Comment: **NEVER** convert dates to varchar for comparison. You are comparing strings, so in the same way "BAAA" is sorted after "ABBB", similarly "02/01" is sorted after "01/02" (because it compares each character working from left to right). If you want SQL Server to treat your values as dates, then keep them as dates. You may also wish to use the culture invariant format `yyyyMMdd`, when you put `01/10/2016`, do you mean 1st October 2016, or 10th January? Remember not all countries use the same date settings.

Comment: Thanks GarethD I has stupidly copied something from part of my code the CONVERT was not needed and now works fine silly me :)

Answer (score -1):

```
    WHERE CASE 
    WHEN [BVContact] IS NOT NULL
        THEN convert(VARCHAR(10), [ContactStarted], 120)
    WHEN [TelephoneConsultationStartedBy] IS NOT NULL
        THEN convert(VARCHAR(10), [TelephoneConsultationStarted], 120)
    WHEN [HomeVisitContactBy] IS NOT NULL
        THEN convert(VARCHAR(10), [HomeVisitContactStarted], 120)
    ELSE ''
    END between '2016-10-01'
    AND '2016-10-02'
```

Comment: this is going to compare a string to a string.